# Simulating Entery Key (by creating InputStream descendant class in Java)

Tags: java, mocking, inputstream, enter

I am trying to create a Mock class, to simulate pressing Enter key after the thread that will be given this InputStream will have worked for 2 seconds.
The thread that reads from this stream uses BufferedReader.readLine() - to wait for Enter key pressed.
What would be the right thing to return in overriden InputStream.read method - to make it work right on any platform?
Would System.lineSeparator().getBytes()[0] be the right value to return?

```
    private static class MockEnterStream extends InputStream {
    private static final long DELAY = 2000;
    public static boolean firstCall = true;
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (firstCall) {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(DELAY);
                firstCall = false;
                return System.lineSeparator().getBytes()[0]; //Enter key
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return -1; // no data
    }
}
```